# SCSS arrow with round corners

Tags: css, sass

I am trying to make out of these arrows, rounded corner arrows.

Here is the sample code:

```
<div class="container">
  <span class="calendar-arrow calendar-arrow-left"></span>
  <span class="calendar-arrow calendar-arrow-right"></span>
</div>
```

And the scss is:

```
@mixin arrow($direction) {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-style: solid !important;
  border-style: inset;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
  border-radius: 3px; /* this does not work well */
  @if $direction == left {
    border-width: 6px 8px 6px 0;
    border-color: transparent #8f9cbc transparent transparent;
  }
  @if $direction == right {
    border-width: 6px 0 6px 8px;
    border-color: transparent transparent transparent #8f9cbc;
  }
}


.container {
  display: flex;
  width: 400px;
  height: 200px;
  background: yellow;
    .calendar-arrow-left {
    @include arrow(left);
    position: absolute;
    top: 28px;
    left: 20px;
  }
  .calendar-arrow-right { 
    @include arrow(right);
    position: absolute;
    top: 28px;
    left: 40px;
  }

}
```

I have searched other solutions, but they seem to have the `content:''` property.
I am wondering if it is possible to fix the above code, without the need to use `content`.

I would appreciate your help.

Here is a [codepen](https://codepen.io/seekman/pen/oNqvQRb).

Edit: these are the sizes of the arrow I need to create:

[image: arrow]

Comment: No, it isn't possible to add border radius in this manner -- the border radius will affect the parts of the border with transparent border-color so you won't be able to see it -- my suggestion is to use an SVG icon

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. That's what I was afraid of. Do you see any other css-only solution that is not .svg?
Maybe embed an svg in `background-image` ? Or some other css only solution?

Answer (score 0):

This way of creating arrows won't let you use/see `border-radius` i.e. rounded corners because you are using transparent borders. You might be able to get the other 2 corners rounded with `border-radius` except the pointed ones (< >) because that is not even 'real' pointing you are seeing, they appear as a result of transparency and actual (border) corners are hidden.

To counter this issue you need to use `transform` and `:before` `:after` pseudo elements to create arrows.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kghosein/95rzgbyh/5/)

Comment: Thank you. That seems to be a great solution, almost what I was looking for. The arrows I need to create are more thin. I just edited the question and added an image. How can I shorten the width of those arrows to reflect the one I posted above? And how to create the top/down arrows? Is there some arrow generator somewhere?